# Getting values of date and time from DialogFragment inside a fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, fragment, timepicker

Hi trying to get the values of the date and time from their respective classes and set them on a text view in the fragment.
Ive tried setting it in a variable and calling it from the method but it doesn't seem to work

Here is my code in the fragment class and i want to set the textviews set_date and set_time

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_timetable, container, false);

    selectDate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.selectDate);
    selectTime = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.selectTime);
    set_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.set_date);
    set_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.set_time);
    selectDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Show Date dialog
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

        }
    });
    selectTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Show time dialog
            DialogFragment newFragment  = new SelectTimeFragment();
            //newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TIME);
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Time Picker");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

SelectDateFragment Class

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private String date = "";
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
    populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
}
public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    date = month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

SelectTimeFragment class

```
public class SelectTimeFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

private String time = "";
public SelectTimeFragment() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    time = String.valueOf(hour) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);

}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use fragment dialog. DatePickerDialog is enough and you should create and show it at onClick of button.

Comment: Focusing just the date field, have you confirmed that you are getting the values that you expect in `onDateSet()`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your Select[Date/Time]Fragment.

```
private void sendResult(int resultCode, Date mDate) {
    if (getTargetFragment() == null)
        return;
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("EXTRA_DATE", mDate);
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, i);
}
```

add this line in your populateSetDate()

```
public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    date = month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
    sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date); //add this
}
```

add this line under dialogFragment instance

```
selectDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.setTargetFragment(TIMETABLE_FRAGMENT, REQUEST_DATE); // add this
        newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

    }
});
```

finally add this method in your TIMETABLE_FRAGMENT

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if (requestCode ==REQUEST_DATE) {
        date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra("EXTRA_DATE"); // this your selected date
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting 2 errors, cannot find symbol REQUEST_DATE and CommonFunctoins in fragment timetable

Comment: Request_date just a unique code. For example; REQUEST_DATE=1234, REQUEST_TIME=5678. You will need those in your onActivtyResult(). Sorry for CommonFunctions :) this is my generic function class.

Comment: Still no luck, should this line be set as is: newFragment.setTargetFragment(newFragment, 1234); Or do i need to replace 'newFragment' with an instance of timetable_fragment

Comment: no you shouldn't. it should be like this. newFragment.setTargetFragment(what_is your_called_fragment,1234). Actually it is a fragment which is parent of onCreateView() in the first quote at your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting the data you expect in `onDateSet`, try the following:

Remove `implements` from `SelectDateFragment` and delete `onDateSet`. Change how you call `DatePickerDialog`.

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment {

private String date = "";

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getParentFragment(), yy, mm, dd);
}

public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    date = month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Add `implements` to the top-level fragment. This is where you will set the date and time. Also, add in `onDateSet` here:

```
Public class YourTopFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

...

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
    set_date.setText(...the text you want to set goes here...);
}
```

This will direct `DialogFragment` to inform your top-level fragment directly of the date selected.

Something similar should work for setting the time.

Comment: [Im getting this error even though i implemented in the fragment which will get the date](https://i.gyazo.com/fd420f4c057ceb2ae03c1fdac8ae53f9.png)

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, although the onDateSet method dosent seem to be running when the date is set

Comment: Check that `getParentFragment()` is not null. If it is, and it probably is since you are nesting fragments, you will need to use a different fragment manager called `getChildFragmentManager`. See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) for more information.

Comment: `getParentFragment()` is definitely the issue. Check out this small [example project](https://github.com/Cheticamp/PickerBase) for an illustration of this technique.